# Conservation of momentum: One moving car hitting another stationary one. Does the target always move forward?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, velocity, collision

Consider an isolated system with two cars of any mass, a ground with friction, and Earth.  Both cars are free to move on the ground.

One car (Car #1) is moving towards the other stationary car (Car #2) at a constant velocity. Based on the conservation of momentum, when they collide, the momentum of Car #1 is transferred to Car #2, which means Car #2 carries non-zero velocity.  Then here is my question:

Does it mean Car #2 moves forward in any case?  That does not add up, because if the force by #2 on #1 is not enough to overcome the static friction by the ground on #1, Car #2 will "stay" on the ground, right? Or is it possible that the momentum transfer occurs as the forward deformation of the internal molecular structure (with non-zero velocity) of Car #2, while Car #2 is still fixed on the ground?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes. Your statement is correct and clear enough.

Comment: That convinces me more.  Thank you!  Then it means the same thing happens when you punch a fixed wall.  The wall does not physically move or slide, but it is internally deformed as the momentum transfers into it

Answer (score 1):

If Car 2 is immovable then the momentum that is lost by Car 1 in the collision is actually “transferred” to the Earth. Of course, the large mass of the Earth means this makes a negligible difference to the Earth’s motion through space.

Comment: When you said "immovable", it sounds like the car is "glued" on the ground and not free to move.  Is that right?

Comment: @TBS500 I just mean that it does not move - either because it is fixed to the ground or because it is so heavy that static friction is sufficient to prevent it from moving. In fact, even if Car 2 does move, any non-zero friction will transfer some momentum to the Earth because of Newton's Third Law.